# What is an integral number?

Tags: notation, terminology

This has nothing to do with integration :)

I've just seen the words 'integral number' used a couple of times and it seems that it means the same thing as an integer; is that correct?

Thanks for the verification.

**EDIT**
For example, this is a question I saw:

> How many differently shaped triangles exist in which no two sides are the
> same length, each side is of ***integral unit length*** and the perimeter of the triangle is
> less than 13 units?

Comment: Can you quote an example sentence?

Comment: This might depend on the context, but I recall that an *algebraic integer* is a complex number which a  root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients (for instance, $i$ is an algebraic integer).

Comment: @J.G. I think I remember a question saying something about a shape with an 'integral side length'. I'm searching for it now.

Comment: @J.G. see now..

Comment: @Bernard see edit.

Comment: Oh, yes. In this context it means an integer (and even a natural number).

Comment: @Bernard thanks, you may want to make that into an answer to make it more easily seen and I'll accept it. In what other context could it be used?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure it's  a really general question – and it's hardly a mathematical question (just about an uncommon terminology).

Comment: @Bernard agreed :) In what other context could it be used?

Comment: It looks like expressed in ordinary  language. Probably when one wants to have  a more or less informal phrasing (just  as I sometimes write that the number $i$ lives in $\mathbf C$).

Comment: @Bernard Ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess was right, but the quoted example is especially idiosyncratic because it says "unit". In normal use, *integral* length would be equal to some integer, while *unit* length would be of length $1$ (see "unit number" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit#Mathematics)). Presumably the author meant, "in the unit ([with a different meaning!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_measurement)) we use to measure lengths, these lengths are integer-valued".

Comment: Thanks for the links and verification :)